# Cannot enable desktop effects using open source ati drivers

Tags: 10.10, ati

I am using the open source ATI drivers in Ubuntu 10.10 because I cannot sleep with the proprietary ones (the machine enters suspend, but will not resume).  However, with the open source ATI drivers I cannot enable desktop effects.  When I go to Settings->Appearance->Visual Effects and click Normal a dialog comes up that says "Searching for available drivers...".  The screen flickers as if it tries to enable desktop effects, but ultimately it messages "Desktop effects could not be enabled."

Note that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver mentions that `drm` could `appear` in dmesg, but it does not.

`lspci -v`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Redwood [Radeon HD 5670] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3060
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at fbec0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fbe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: radeon
```

`LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`

```
name of display: :0.0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_hyperpipe, 
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.9-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_logic_op, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_convolution, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_histogram, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_paletted_texture, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_shared_texture_palette, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, 
    GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_resize_buffers, GL_MESA_texture_array, 
    GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fragment_program, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_point_sprite, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_OES_read_format, GL_SGI_color_matrix, 
    GL_SGI_color_table, GL_SGI_texture_color_table, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check here: http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/ATIRadeon

you will see that our 5XXX cards are not supported yet officially.  However, 2D is supported, as explained in the following post:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Nzk0Ng

Note it mentions that hardware acceleration was being worked on.

In short: patience!  Soon it'll have hardware acceleration supported, but not yet.

Comment: Of course, now we know that it DOES work - the latest Mesa has full 5XXX card support.